# How to make routes for this URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
GET /bids?countries=us,uk&categories=finance,sports&channels=ca,ga
```

And the expected response is:

```
{
  "bids": [
    { 'country': 'us', 'category': 'finance', 'channel': 'ca', 'amount': 4.0 },
    { 'country': 'us', 'category': 'finance', 'channel': '2ga', 'amount': 2.0 },
    { 'country': 'us', 'category': 'sports', 'channel': 'ca', 'amount': 2.0 },
    { 'country': 'us', 'category': 'sports', 'channel': 'ga', 'amount': 2.0 },
    { 'country': 'uk', 'category': 'finance', 'channel': 'ca', 'amount': 1.0 },
    { 'country': 'uk', 'category': 'finance', 'channel': 'ga', 'amount': 1.0 },
    { 'country': 'uk', 'category': 'sports', 'channel': 'ca', 'amount': 3.0 },
    { 'country': 'uk', 'category': 'sports', 'channel': 'ga', 'amount': 3.0 }
  ]
}
```

How to make routes for this url please help me out - any more experienced people know what I am doing for making routes ?. thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited. Just use tags that are relevant to the actual subject. Tacking on a bunch of version tags or completely unrelated tags like "rubygems" won't give your question more attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a plain old index route with some extra query string parameters to filter the resource. You don't actually need to do anything special.

```
resources :bids, only: [:index]
```

```
class BidsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /bids
  # GET /bids?countries=us,uk&categories=finance,sports&channels=ca,ga
  def index
    @bids = Bid.all
    # @todo implement filters
  end
end
```

When matching a request URI with a route Rails will typically ignore the query string parameters unless they correspond to named placeholders in a defined route - `GET /bids?id=1` for example will match `GET /bids/:id`.

Query string parameters are available in the `params` object. Just like parameters extraced from placeholders in the URI and are parsed identically to formdata in the body.